# Optimisation of Shadow Casting Python

Tags: python, optimization, pygame, shadow, bresenham

I have been working on a Shadow Caster for a small RPG I'm doing.

The trouble I have is that when I use it in my game it is just way way way to slow and induces a horrible lag.

Please do not be too frighten by the lenght of the post. It is fairly straightforward but so that you can run the code I included all the Bresenham's algorithms as well.

The principle is as follow:
- make a black surface
- define a light source with a position and a radius.
- get all the points on the circumference of the circle defined by this position and radius using Bresenham's Circle Algorithm.
- for each point along the circumference draw a ligne from the position of the light source using Bresenham's Line Algorithm.
- then iterate over the points of the line and check if they collide with every obstacle displayed on the screen.
- If there is no collision draw a WHITE circle centered on that point with a radius of 10 pixels or so.
- If there is a collision move on to the next point along the circle circumference.
- finally blit the surface with all the white circles on a surface which has a transparency value of 100 for the black color and a full transparency for the WHITE color.

So far I have attempted the following:
Which did reduce the lag:
- restrict the obstacle list to the ones displayed on the screen
- consider the screen edges as obstacles to reduce the iteration of area not visible.
- iterate only over every 3 points around the circle and 12 points along the lines.
Which didn't change anything:
- using ellipses going from the light source to the edge of the range or the obstacle instead of lots of circles along the line. The problem was that I had to redraw surface for each ellipse and then rotate the whole lot.

If you have any suggestions on how to make this more efficient I would be happy to here then.

Bresenham's Line Algo:

```
def get_line(start, end):
    """Bresenham's Line Algorithm
    Produces a list of tuples from start and end

    >>> points1 = get_line((0, 0), (3, 4))
    >>> points2 = get_line((3, 4), (0, 0))
    >>> assert(set(points1) == set(points2))
    >>> print points1
    [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
    >>> print points2
    [(3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (0, 0)]
    """
    # Setup initial conditions
    x1, y1 = start
    x2, y2 = end
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1

    # Determine how steep the line is
    is_steep = abs(dy) > abs(dx)

    # Rotate line
    if is_steep:
        x1, y1 = y1, x1
        x2, y2 = y2, x2

    # Swap start and end points if necessary and store swap state
    swapped = False
    if x1 > x2:
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
        y1, y2 = y2, y1
        swapped = True

    # Recalculate differentials
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1

    # Calculate error
    error = int(dx / 2.0)
    ystep = 1 if y1 < y2 else -1

    # Iterate over bounding box generating points between start and end
    y = y1
    points = []
    for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
        coord = (y, x) if is_steep else (x, y)
        points.append(coord)
        error -= abs(dy)
        if error < 0:
            y += ystep
            error += dx

    # Reverse the list if the coordinates were swapped
    if swapped:
        points.reverse()
    return points
```

Bresenham's Circle Algo:

```
def get_circle((dx,dy),radius):
    "Bresenham complete circle algorithm in Python"
    # init vars
    switch = 3 - (2 * radius)
    points = set()
    x = 0
    y = radius
    # first quarter/octant starts clockwise at 12 o'clock
    while x <= y:
        # first quarter first octant
        points.add((x,-y))
        # first quarter 2nd octant
        points.add((y,-x))
        # second quarter 3rd octant
        points.add((y,x))
        # second quarter 4.octant
        points.add((x,y))
        # third quarter 5.octant
        points.add((-x,y))        
        # third quarter 6.octant
        points.add((-y,x))
        # fourth quarter 7.octant
        points.add((-y,-x))
        # fourth quarter 8.octant
        points.add((-x,-y))
        if switch < 0:
            switch = switch + (4 * x) + 6
        else:
            switch = switch + (4 * (x - y)) + 10
            y = y - 1
        x = x + 1
    offset_points = set()
    for pt in points:
        offset_points.add((pt[0]+dx,pt[1]+dy))

    return offset_points

def shadow_gen(shadow_surf,source,cir_pt,obstacles):
    line_points = get_line(source.pos,cir_pt)
    for line_pt in line_points[0::12]:
        for obs in obstacles:
            pygame.draw.circle(shadow_surf, WHITE, line_pt, 20, 0) #radius to 5px and 0 to fill the circle
            if obs.rect.collidepoint(line_pt) or pygame.Rect(0,0,500,500).collidepoint(line_pt) == False:
                return
```

My Classes for the light sources, obstacles and shadow mask:

```
class Obstacle(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((150,150))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((x,y),(150,150))
        self.surf.fill(pygame.color.Color('blue'))

class Light_Source(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,range_):
        self.range = range_
        self.pos = (x,y)


class Night_Mask(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((500,500)) #Screenwidth and height
        self.alpha = 100
        self.light_sources = []

        '''setting initial alpha and colorkey'''
        self.surf.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.surf.set_alpha(self.alpha)


    def apply_shadows(self, obstacles):
        shadow_surf = pygame.Surface((500,500))
        for source in self.light_sources:
            circle_pts = list(get_circle(source.pos,source.range))
            for cir_pt in circle_pts[0::3]:
                shadow_gen(shadow_surf,source,cir_pt,obstacles)
        self.surf.blit(shadow_surf, (0, 0))
```

The shadow generation functions which allows me to break out of both line and obstacle loop without using an exception in my apply_shadows method of the Night_Mask class:

```
def shadow_gen(shadow_surf,source,cir_pt,obstacles):
    line_points = get_line(source.pos,cir_pt)
    for line_pt in line_points[0::12]:
        for obs in obstacles:
            pygame.draw.circle(shadow_surf, WHITE, line_pt, 20, 0) #radius to 5px and 0 to fill the circle
            if obs.rect.collidepoint(line_pt) or pygame.Rect(0,0,500,500).collidepoint(line_pt) == False:
                return
```

And finally the main pygame example loop to run all of the above:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

bg = pygame.Surface((500,500))
bg.fill(pygame.color.Color('yellow'))

ob_a = Obstacle(75,80)
ls = Light_Source(75,75,300)
night_m = Night_Mask()
night_m.light_sources.extend([ls])

while True:  
    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('black'))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    ls.pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    night_m.apply_shadows([ob_a])

    screen.blit(bg, (0,  0))
    screen.blit(ob_a.surf,ob_a.rect)
    screen.blit(night_m.surf, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Here is the entire code from start to finish for an easy copy paste:

```
import pygame
import sys

WHITE = (255,255,255)
'''FUNCTIONS'''
def get_line(start, end):
    """Bresenham's Line Algorithm
    Produces a list of tuples from start and end

    >>> points1 = get_line((0, 0), (3, 4))
    >>> points2 = get_line((3, 4), (0, 0))
    >>> assert(set(points1) == set(points2))
    >>> print points1
    [(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
    >>> print points2
    [(3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (0, 0)]
    """
    # Setup initial conditions
    x1, y1 = start
    x2, y2 = end
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1

    # Determine how steep the line is
    is_steep = abs(dy) > abs(dx)

    # Rotate line
    if is_steep:
        x1, y1 = y1, x1
        x2, y2 = y2, x2

    # Swap start and end points if necessary and store swap state
    swapped = False
    if x1 > x2:
        x1, x2 = x2, x1
        y1, y2 = y2, y1
        swapped = True

    # Recalculate differentials
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1

    # Calculate error
    error = int(dx / 2.0)
    ystep = 1 if y1 < y2 else -1

    # Iterate over bounding box generating points between start and end
    y = y1
    points = []
    for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
        coord = (y, x) if is_steep else (x, y)
        points.append(coord)
        error -= abs(dy)
        if error < 0:
            y += ystep
            error += dx

    # Reverse the list if the coordinates were swapped
    if swapped:
        points.reverse()
    return points

def get_circle((dx,dy),radius):
    "Bresenham complete circle algorithm in Python"
    # init vars
    switch = 3 - (2 * radius)
    points = set()
    x = 0
    y = radius
    # first quarter/octant starts clockwise at 12 o'clock
    while x <= y:
        # first quarter first octant
        points.add((x,-y))
        # first quarter 2nd octant
        points.add((y,-x))
        # second quarter 3rd octant
        points.add((y,x))
        # second quarter 4.octant
        points.add((x,y))
        # third quarter 5.octant
        points.add((-x,y))        
        # third quarter 6.octant
        points.add((-y,x))
        # fourth quarter 7.octant
        points.add((-y,-x))
        # fourth quarter 8.octant
        points.add((-x,-y))
        if switch < 0:
            switch = switch + (4 * x) + 6
        else:
            switch = switch + (4 * (x - y)) + 10
            y = y - 1
        x = x + 1
    offset_points = set()
    for pt in points:
        offset_points.add((pt[0]+dx,pt[1]+dy))

    return offset_points

def shadow_gen(shadow_surf,source,cir_pt,obstacles):
    line_points = get_line(source.pos,cir_pt)
    for line_pt in line_points[0::12]:
        for obs in obstacles:
            pygame.draw.circle(shadow_surf, WHITE, line_pt, 20, 0) #radius to 5px and 0 to fill the circle
            if obs.rect.collidepoint(line_pt) or pygame.Rect(0,0,500,500).collidepoint(line_pt) == False:
                return

'''CLASSES'''                
class Obstacle(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((150,150))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((x,y),(150,150))
        self.surf.fill(pygame.color.Color('blue'))

class Light_Source(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,range_):
        self.range = range_
        self.pos = (x,y)


class Night_Mask(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((500,500)) #Screenwidth and height
        self.alpha = 100
        self.light_sources = []


        '''setting initial alpha and colorkey'''
        self.surf.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.surf.set_alpha(self.alpha)


    def apply_shadows(self, obstacles):
        shadow_surf = pygame.Surface((500,500))
        for source in self.light_sources:
            circle_pts = list(get_circle(source.pos,source.range))
            for cir_pt in circle_pts[0::3]:
                shadow_gen(shadow_surf,source,cir_pt,obstacles)
        self.surf.blit(shadow_surf, (0, 0))


'''MAIN GAME'''
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

bg = pygame.Surface((500,500))
bg.fill(pygame.color.Color('yellow'))

ob_a = Obstacle(75,80)
ls = Light_Source(75,75,300)
night_m = Night_Mask()
night_m.light_sources.extend([ls])

while True:  
    screen.fill(pygame.color.Color('black'))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    ls.pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    night_m.apply_shadows([ob_a])

    screen.blit(bg, (0,  0))
    screen.blit(ob_a.surf,ob_a.rect)
    screen.blit(night_m.surf, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lag issue appears to be coming from the method `Night_Mask.apply_shadows(self, obstacles)`. This appears to be due to the pure amount of iterations the nested for loop needs to go through.

Reducing the value of `range_` in the constructor of `Light_Source(x, y, range_)` reduces the lag by reducing the aforementioned methods iterations, but the visual effect is worse. I found that the fps started to really drop for me after setting the variable past ~65-70.

There is a Pygame graphics library, that handles shadows very well.

Link to the page:http://pygame.org/project-Pygame+Advanced+Graphics+Library-660-4586.html
Direct download for version 8.1.1 from site:[link](http://www.geometrian.com/data/programming/projects/Pygame%20Advanced%20Graphics%20Library/8.1.1/PAdLib8.1.1.zip)

This is the description of the library from the site:

> This is an all purpose graphics library for easily creating complicated effects quickly, and with a minimum of code. Run the very well commented examples, each less than a page long (not counting comments), and learn how to make complicated effects like shadows and antialiasing.

Here is an image from the page showing an example of shadows.
[image]

I downloaded and tested the library, and it works very well. I tested on Pygame1.9.2a0 for python 3.4

I believe this to be the easiest fix for your problem, and should help you with future projects as well. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've managed to get it to work in the end but it is still much less efficient than this library you recommend. So I'll use it instead :D

Comment: I'm happy I could help.